# Can't compile android GoogleAdMobAdsSdk 6.3.1 or 6.4.1

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

When I update admob sdk to 6.4.1 and try run project I get this error:

```
[2013-05-15 16:52:32 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
[2013-05-15 16:52:32 - BannerSample] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
```

I try with my app and with empty admob BannerSample and getting same error.
I update latest android sdk and tools.

I've tried and I've changed eclipse.ini to

```
-startup
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
 --launcher.library

 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
 -showsplash

 org.eclipse.platform
 --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
 512m
 --launcher.defaultAction
 openFile
 -vmargs
 -Xms1024m
 -Xmx1024m
```

But nothing helps, the last version that works is 6.2.1

I have windows 7 64bit 8GB RAM and Eclipse 3.7.2.

Comment: What's the full error? You seem to have truncated it.

Comment: It is full error, I've tried all things but it was not worth it.

When I downloaded new version of Eclipse 4.2.2 everything works without problems.